# Apache 2 + Xdebug + PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 not working

Tags: php, xdebug, apache2.4

I am not able to step through my code. It works fine in 16.04. I dual boot into 18.04 and configured *Apache 2*, *Xdebug*, *PHP 7.2* the same way but I cannot seem to stop at any of my break points.

The debugger stops ONE TIME at the *first line* (as that is how I have it configured in *NetBeans 8.2*). After that the debugger never breaks again. I disabled *opcache* to see if that was interfering but it didn't seem to help.

Note that if I debug a PHP-CLI application then *Xdebug* works fine. It seems to be an *Apache 2* related configuration issue and I cannot seem to determine why.

Here is my *20-xdebug.ini* file:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
#xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level=300
```

Comment: If it stops at line ONE then its working. Are you sure you have reset the breakpoints? Will it allow you to step through the code from LINE ONE?

Comment: Yes, it does stop on line one, I can step through. That works. However, any subsequent web calls to the PHP application (Laravel) never break again - including line one break. It's as if xdebug terminated even though NetBeans still says it's connected.

Comment: You are clicking through the site normally I assume and not launching pages seperately?

Comment: I just stumbled onto why. Apparently ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug  must be part of the URL or xdebug will not honor the request. This is new to me. It worked fine in Ubunutu 16.04. If I manually add that to the URL then it breaks. However, this doesn't work for AJAX calls and such.

Comment: You launch the site with XDEBUG and then you have to do everything from that launch windows. So click throuhg the site from the homepage to where you want to test just as a normal user would have to

Comment: I know that but that doesn't work. Laravel is writing friendly URLs and the ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug is no longer present.

Comment: It does not need to be. Once the connection is made to a browser tab anything done in that browser tab should be watched by XDEBUG **BUT ONLY THAT BROWSER TAB**

Answer (score 2):

*Argh!!!!*

Found the issue. For some reason my browser had cookies disabled therefore XDEBUG could not store its cookie thus all subsequent calls back to the web application from the browser were not processed via XDEBUG.